# How do I draw a line along the center of the object

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to measure the width of banana by using these 2 lines. First line is the contour around the banana:

[image]

and second line is the middle line of banana:

[image]

As you can see in the picture I've tried using [skeletonization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvDZZ.png) method, but it has some noise and the line isn't connected (it actually has multiple line overlaping to each others). I want the red line to be a single line without noise like this:

[image]

so I can calculate the width from it.

Update: now I can remove all the noisy pixels the result look like this:

[image: no noisy banana]

But the line is discontinuous, I need a continuous one.

The reason why I want this redline done is a bit hard to explain, but I want to find the longest width by drawing a perpendicular line like this:

[image: result]

Another update: Now I can connect all these lines by drawing a line to the closet two points the result look like this [image: done]

Comment: Maybe add the images within the question, instead of links, just for convenience.

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Comment: Just upload the images to your question

Comment: I upload it and it becomes a link

Comment: it said "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: oh shoot. Tragic!

Comment: A skeleton line is by definition connected and a single pixel thick, you should question the algorithm you use to get it. To get rid of the spurious lines, you can erase the short arcs. But I am curious to know why you would need the centerline to measure the width.

Comment: Now i can remove all the noisy pixels, but the line is broken and not connected together anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: @Patrick is it time consuming to calculate closest two points?

Comment: @Lamp yes, but very short time. it also depends on the image size.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. You don’t need to find the center line to compute the width. Instead, use the distance transform, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77747415/7328782 — the max of the distance transform is the max width of the banana.

Comment: See FilFinder at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481596/python-image-finding-largest-branch-from-image-skeleton

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer explains how to find the thickest part of a contour. There are four steps to this answer. You have already accomplished some of these steps, for clarity I will reiterate them in this answer.

Step 1: Detect the skeleton

[image: skeleton]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

# Read image
src = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/banana.png')
img = src.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = np.zeros_like(gray)

# Find contours in image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[1]

# Draw skeleton of banana on the mask
img = gray.copy()
size = np.size(img)
skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)
ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,5,255,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
done = False
while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
    img = eroded.copy() 
    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
    if zeros==size: done = True
kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
skel = cv2.dilate(skel, kernel, iterations=1)
skeleton_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skel, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
largest_skeleton_contour = max(skeleton_contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

Step 2: Elongate the contour to the edges of the image

[image: scipy to extend skeleton]

```
# Extend the skeleton past the edges of the banana
points = []
for point in largest_skeleton_contour: points.append(tuple(point[0]))
x,y = zip(*points)
z = np.polyfit(x,y,7)
f = np.poly1d(z)
x_new = np.linspace(0, img.shape[1],300)
y_new = f(x_new)
extension = list(zip(x_new, y_new))
img = src.copy()
for point in range(len(extension)-1):
    a = tuple(np.array(extension[point], int))
    b = tuple(np.array(extension[point+1], int))
    cv2.line(img, a, b, (0,0,255), 1)
    cv2.line(mask, a, b, 255, 1)   
mask_px = np.count_nonzero(mask)
```

Step 3: Find distance between points in the contour, only look at distances that cross the skeleton line

[image: distances that cross the skeleton line]

```
# Find the distance between points in the contour of the banana
# Only look at distances that cross the mid line
def is_collision(mask_px, mask, a, b):
    temp_image = mask.copy()
    cv2.line(temp_image, a, b, 0, 2)
    new_total = np.count_nonzero(temp_image)
    if new_total != mask_px: return True
    else: return False

def distance(a,b): return math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)

distances = []
for point_a in cnt[:int(len(cnt)/2)]:
    temp_distance = 0
    close_distance = img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]
    close_points = (0,0),(0,0)
    for point_b in cnt:
        A, B = tuple(point_a[0]), tuple(point_b[0])
        dist = distance(tuple(point_a[0]), tuple(point_b[0]))
        if is_collision(mask_px, mask, A, B):
            if dist < close_distance:
                close_points = A, B
                close_distance = dist
    cv2.line(img, close_points[0], close_points[1], (234,234,123), 1)
    distances.append((close_distance, close_points))
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Step 4: Find the maximum distance:

[image: maximum distance]

```
max_thickness = max(distances)
a, b = max_thickness[1][0], max_thickness[1][1]
cv2.line(img, a, b, (0,255,0), 4)
print("maximum thickness = ", max_thickness[0])
```

Comment: @Patrick Sure! I love learning from these interesting questions. If this satisfactorily answers your question, can you click the check mark to the left of my answer to accept it?

Comment: i got error: `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long` at line `b = tuple(np.array(extension[point+1], int))`

Comment: @Zorro This answer only works if the red line is a function. The banana has to be in the same orientation as in the example.