# Is there any method to remove branches of skeleton?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

I want  to remove all small branches in the skeleton as shown in output image. My idea is  as follows :

1. Get skeleton of image.
2. Find the junction pixel that has two or more neighbor pixel.
3. Remove those junction pixel.
4. Create data structure for each segment of skeleton.
5. Calculate length of each segment of skeleton.
6. Remove the segment that has lesser length or some threshold.
7. Recombine all segment with junction pixel.

Input Image[image: Input Image]

Output Image [image: Output Image]

Comment: You’ve stated what you want to do, but failed to ask a question. Please read [ask]. Please note that this is a site where people answer your questions about programming, they don’t do programming work for you for free.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Image - Finding largest branch from image skeleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481596/python-image-finding-largest-branch-from-image-skeleton) See the second answer there, not the accepted one.

Comment: @HansHirse I have already tried this answer, but could not solve my problem.