How to remove burrs after extracting the image skeleton?
I have a binary image, and I used the skeleton method in the Skimage library to extract skeleton lines. However, there are many burrs on both edges, and I want to remove and delete these burrs.
This is skeletonized images by two different methods

Original Images

my python script is:
import skimage as ski
import skimage.io as io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc("font",family='Microsoft YaHei')
image_path=r"./1089_8.jpg"
image=io.imread(image_path,as_gray=True)
skeleton1=skeletonize(image,method='zhang')
skeleton2=skeletonize(image,method='lee')
fig,axes=plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3,figsize=(8, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax=axes.ravel()
ax[0].imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0].axis('off')
ax[0].set_title('original', fontsize=20)
ax[1].imshow(skeleton1, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[1].set_title('Zhang_method', fontsize=20)
ax[2].imshow(skeleton2,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[2].axis('off')
ax[2].set_title('lee_method',fontsize=20)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

I want to remove and delete these burrs. Then calculate the length of binary images.
My Desired Outcome
The result should look like figure (c).


Welcome to stack overflow. This question could benefit from an [edit] - what is your python script doing (or not doing) that caused you to ask this question?

context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78919328/how-can-i-skeltonize-my-images-by-skimage-removing-burrs-and-extract-crack-cnet

You do realize that the image under the caption "original" and the image under the caption "Original Images" is not the same image?

The main problem with your input image is that you consider it binary, while in reality it is only "almost binary":
You are working with a JPEG image, JPEG usually uses lossy compression and thus will have compression artefacts. You will not see these compression artefacts with your bare eye, but they will nevertheless interfere with the skeletonization algorithm.
Here is a contrast-enhanced version of your given image:

As you can see, there are a lot of tiny gray regions around the white structures. These are the ones responsible for the burrs that you struggle with.
Proposed solution
A quick fix: Make your image truly binary, e.g. by replacing
image=io.imread(image_path,as_gray=True)

with
# Threshold image: values > 127 become 1, values ≤ 127 become 0
image = (io.imread(image_path, as_gray=True) > 127).astype(np.uint8)

and thus applying a threshold before applying skeletonize().
This, for me, results in the following skeleton for Zhang's method:

And for Lee's method, I get:

You will still need to deal with a few burrs and the second "arm" in your desired length calculation; however, I would not consider this as the task of the skeletonization approach, as these are actual parts of the structure in your image rather than artefacts.
Here is the full code to reproduce the results from above:
import skimage.io as io
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
import numpy as np

# TODO: Adjust input and output paths as necessary
in_path = "stackoverflow/OlfxVca1.jpg"
out_path_zhang = "stackoverflow/zhang.png"
out_path_lee = "stackoverflow/lee.png"

# Threshold image: values > 127 become 1, values ≤ 127 become 0
image = (io.imread(in_path, as_gray=True) > 127).astype(np.uint8)

skeleton_zhang = skeletonize(image, method="zhang").astype(np.uint8)
skeleton_lee = skeletonize(image, method="lee").astype(np.uint8)

io.imsave("stackoverflow/zhang.png", skeleton_zhang * 255)
io.imsave("stackoverflow/lee.png", skeleton_lee * 255)



I appreciate it, and now I know how to handle it, Thank you so much. Btw as you mentioned JPG images will interfere with the skeletonization algorithm. So can I convert the format and it will help my next research? The above image is a road crack image, and I want to calculate the length and width of the crack by pixel.

Regarding JPG and format conversions: If you have your original crack images in an image format that does not use lossy compression (e.g. PNG) then keep them in the original format. If all your crack images are JPG images, then simply converting them to another format will not help, because this process will not "magically" make the images binary again. What you could do instead is: (1) Load JPG image, (2) apply threshold to make it truly binary (as I do in the code above), (3) store result from applying threshold in an image format that does not use lossy compression (e.g. PNG, BMP, TIF).

wow, awesome I appreciate it, thank you so much.  I just ran this code《https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481596/python-image-finding-largest-branch-from-image-skeleton/78923157#78923157》 and encountered the following error after running it：
from astropy.config.configuration import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'update_default_config' from 'astropy.config.configuration' (E:\python3.10\lib\site-packages\astropy\config\configuration.py)

@Abukeram This is a question someone else has to answer, I am afraid.

That's okay, thank you so much for your help
