# Using skimage and fil_finder in measuring the length of skeleton

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm trying to measure the longest and the transverse branchs of a banana picture, using skimage to get the skeleton and then using fil_finder to get the length of the longest branch , the code is adapted from this post

[Ideas how to measure the length of a skeleton using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979742/ideas-how-to-measure-the-length-of-a-skeleton-using-python)

but i can't get it fil_finder to work with the skeleton output of skimage, i get the following error:

```
raise TypeError("Data must be 2D. Please re-check the inputs.")
TypeError: Data must be 2D. Please re-check the inputs.
```

[skeleton made using skimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJrx2.png)
[banana picture used in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHE62.jpg)

any help solving the error and updates to code if any needed to measure the length of longest and transverse length

```
from skimage import io,img_as_float
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.util import invert
import numpy as np
from fil_finder import FilFinder2D
import astropy.units as u

image=img_as_float(io.imread('C:/python/fruits/banana.jpg'))


gray = invert(image)
skeleton=skeletonize(gray)


fil = FilFinder2D(skeleton, distance=250 * u.pc, mask=skeleton)
fil.preprocess_image(flatten_percent=85)
fil.create_mask(border_masking=True, verbose=False,
use_existing_mask=True)
fil.medskel(verbose=False)
fil.analyze_skeletons(branch_thresh=40* u.pix, skel_thresh=10 * u.pix, prune_criteria='length')

plt.imshow(fil.skeleton, cmap='gray')
plt.contour(fil.skeleton_longpath, colors='r')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: what is the shape of the skeleton image? You can find out by typing print(skeleton.shape)

Answer (score 0):

(1) Your image is probably RGB (color), and

(2) it needs to be *binary* (black and white, not even gray) to be skeletonized.

So, you need to do:

```py
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import filters

image_rgb = img_as_float(io.imread('C:/python/fruits/banana.jpg'))

image_gray = invert(rgb2gray(image_rgb))
image_binary = image_gray > filters.threshold_otsu(image_gray)  # for example

skeleton = skeletonize(image_binary)
```

(3) Disclaimer: I am the main author of skan, but just thought I'd throw it out there as an alternative to filfinder: an n-dimensional skeleton analysis tool: https://jni.github.io/skan/