# skan.Skeleton returning integer (not skeleton object)

Tags: scikit-image, mathematical-morphology

Sorry, this might turn out to be a very basic problem but I'm stumped:

I'm trying to get the lengths of skeleton branches. I'm able to skeletonize my image and can see the skeleton with draw.overlay_skeleton_2d() but when I try to get any statistics on the skeleton back I get an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5924e1b8ffc8> in <module>
      4 # fig, ax = plt.subplots()
      5 # draw.overlay_skeleton_2d(img, skeleton0, dilate=1, axes=ax)
----> 6 branch_data = summarize(Skeleton(skeleton0))
      7 branch_data.head()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\skan\csr.py in __init__(self, skeleton_image, spacing, source_image, _buffer_size_offset, keep_images, junction_mode, unique_junctions)
    383         self.nbgraph = csr_to_nbgraph(graph, pixel_values)
    384         self.coordinates = coords
--> 385         self.paths = _build_skeleton_path_graph(
    386                 self.nbgraph, _buffer_size_offset=_buffer_size_offset
    387                 )

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\skan\csr.py in _build_skeleton_path_graph(graph, _buffer_size_offset)
    259 def _build_skeleton_path_graph(graph, *, _buffer_size_offset=None):
    260     if _buffer_size_offset is None:
--> 261         max_num_cycles = graph.indices.size // 4
    262         _buffer_size_offset = max_num_cycles
    263     degrees = np.diff(graph.indptr)

TypeError: expected dtype object, got 'numpy.dtype[int32]'
```

Any tips would be great. I'm still a Python beginner so, like I said, the mistake might be a very basic one.

Rgds,

Olie

*Edits included

This is my code:

```
import cv2
from skan import draw, skeleton_to_csgraph, Skeleton, summarize
from skimage import morphology
# import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

# load image and convert to bool
img = cv2.imread(save_p + "\\" + img_name + ".png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = img.astype(bool)

# skeletonize
skeleton0 = morphology.skeletonize(img)

### check skeleton
# fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# draw.overlay_skeleton_2d(img, skeleton0, dilate=1, axes=ax)

### from Documentation (linked below)
branch_data = summarize(Skeleton(skeleton0))      # ignoring scaling for now
branch_data.head()

# Skel_obj = Skeleton(skeleton0)        # testing this but same problem
# Skel_obj.path_lengths(0)
```

I have attempted to follow a couple of posts ([e.g. this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244206/using-skimage-and-fil-finder-in-measuring-the-length-of-skeleton) but for that particular case the module wont install and anyway... it seems like skan.summarize is exactly what I need - [documentation](https://skeleton-analysis.org/stable/getting_started/getting_started.html#measuring-the-length-of-skeleton-branches)

Name: numpy
Version: 1.23.4

Name: scikit-image
Version: 0.19.3

Name: pandas
Version: 1.3.4

Name: skan
Version: 0.10.0

Name: numba
Version: 0.50.1

Windows 10 PC

[image: binary image]

Comment: Can you edit your issue to include (a) the full error message, not just the TypeError? The message tells you exactly which lines of code are problematic, (b) an example image so we can run your code, (c) complete code that we can run (including imports), and (d) versions of numpy, scikit-image, pandas, and skan that you are using?

Comment: Discovered I couldn't upgrade numba - sorted out that problem, upgraded to version 0.56.4 and now got things to work.